# Icomoon icons breaking sometimes in production version

Tags: css, reactjs, encoding, fonts, icomoon

Sometimes the icons break and seems like the screenshots
This only happens in the build version, locally doesn't.
I made this font icons using icomoon

[image]

[image]

I've tried to define the charset to UTF-8 in icons.scss file but doesn't worked.

Comment: Please [*do not* use (sole) images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3439404) in your [mcve].
Copy the actual text, paste it into the question, then format it as code.

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python*): `'\ue9b1 \ue9b2 \ue9b3 \ue9b4 \ue9b5 \ue9b6 \ue9b7 \ue9b8'.encode('utf-8').decode('cp1252')` returns `î¦± î¦² î¦³ î¦´ î¦µ î¦¶ î¦· î¦¸`.